# Trying to read data from Mongo

Tags: javascript, mongodb, vue.js, backend

so I already have the data in Mongo, but the problem is the Mongo doesn't read properly the data from the backend. This is my backend code:

```
app.get ('/posts', async (req , res) => {
let db = await connect();
let posts = req.body;
res.send(posts); 
});
```

and the code from services:

```
async get_posts() {
    let response = await Service.get(/posts)
    let doc = response.doc;
        return {
            id: doc._id,
            email: doc.email,
            title: doc.title,
            imageDesc: doc.imageDesc,
            img: doc.img,

        };

}
```

Comment: Where is the database read code?

Comment: Isn't this ? let db = await connect();

Comment: That code connects to the db. Some examples of reading a document: [MongoDB NodeJS Driver - Find Examples](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/usage-examples/findOne/).

Comment: Can you show me the right code in answers? Would appreciate

Comment: To read the data from a collection, use the [find](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#find) method.

Comment: It returns that every data is undefined , but in frontend it fetch the get method from the backend.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the instance of the db, and an instance to the collection in order to retrieve the posts.

For instance:

```
app.get ('/posts', async (req , res) => {
    const postsCollection = db.collection("posts");
    const posts = await postsCollection.find();
    return res.json(posts);
});
```

Read the mongo documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/usage-examples/findOne/)